# How to avoid error "Value too large for defined data type"?

Tags: permissions

i am using Ubuntu 18.04.  When i try to change permissions of just mounted folder some times i get this error. Some times all is done without this error. The folders are almost the same size and type.

Comment: what do you mean by mounted folder?

Comment: i use this command: mount -t ubifs /dev/ubi0_0 /mnt/ubifs and after that i try to change permissions of /mnt/ubifs with chmod -R 444 /mnt/ubifs. This sometimes is done and sometimes endss with this error.

Comment: doesn't `mount -o ro` (read only) do the same thing? Is there a particular reason you need to change permissions?

Comment: i want to view some files.

Comment: you can view files if you mount read only, you just can't write them, the same as when you change permissions to 444

Comment: i don't wanna write them, but i can't view them because of this error.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?
We are having the same problem with a mounted location in a Azure Kubernetes Service Pods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849252/azure-disk-pvc-on-aks-value-too-large-for-defined-data-type-at-mounted-locati

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mount -t ubifs -o ro /dev/ubi0_0 /mnt/ubifs` to mount read only, so you don't have to change permissions any more.